# Audio/Video muxer which works in command line or API?

Tags: video, audio, video-conversion, avidemux

I am looking for a audio/video muxer which can work without user intervention like in a command line or API. I tried [Avidemux](http://avidemux.org/) but it seems to be finicky. Sometimes it works and many times not.

Is there any other tool which just works every time? I don't mind if it's commercial.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Try a windows build of [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) or even [WinFF](http://winff.org/html_new/). 
 FFmpeg doesn't have the video editing features of Avidemux but it sounds like you don't need them anyway.

Here's a [good howto document](http://www.itbroadcastanddigitalcinema.com/ffmpeg_howto.html) to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Try MLT framework http://www.mltframework.org/

It exposes API in C++,Python.
It also has an CLI called melt which can do almost all Non-Linear editing jobs